# OS/2 grep had a great feature where it would show you n lines BEFORE the search item was found. Is there an equivalent in unix anywhere?

Tags: unix, grep, ibm

Solaris would be preferable, but I'll take linux or something I can compile. Does such a beast exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get GNU grep and it's dependencies for Solaris from [sunfreeware.com](http://sunfreeware.com/) either as a binary download in pkg format which installs in /usr/local/bin or as a source package.

Answer (score 19):

As far as GNU grep go, this will show you the number of lines before the match:

```
# grep -B number
```

Equivilent for after:

```
# grep -A number
```

You can download GNU Grep here: http://www.gnu.org/s/grep/

Comment: And `-C` combines both `A` and `B` in one flag.

Answer (score 2):

A small awk script will also work:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { context=3; }
{ add_buffer($0) }
/pattern/ { print_buffer() }
function add_buffer(line)
{
    buffer[NR % context]=line
}
function print_buffer()
{
    for(i = max(1, NR-context+1); i <= NR; i++) {
        print buffer[i % context]
    }
}
function max(a,b)
{
    if (a > b) { return a } else { return b }
}
```

replace `/pattern/` with the actual regular expression or pattern to search for.